# Adding a field to an existing Django model

Tags: django-models

I have a little website with a few users and I'd like to add a field to one of my models (and hence tables.)  The problem is that `syncdb` of course won't touch the existing models and I'm trying to figure out how to add this field to the model/table without having to repopulate the entire thing.

Example:

```
class Newspaper(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(user, unique=True)
    reads = models.ManyToManyField(Newspaper)
```

Now I'd like to add a URL field (`blank=True`) to the `Newspaper` model without breaking the user profiles.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this. However there are a number of third-party projects that will do it for you. The two leading ones are called [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) and [django-evolution](http://code.google.com/p/django-evolution/), although there are various others as well (including one I've been involved with, dmigrations).

I would definitely recommend South - it has a number of really neat features and works really well.

Comment: I think it's also a good idea to get comfortable altering your databases yourself, especially when it's simple operations like adding a new column or constraint.  It's a great way to learn the basics of relationship databases, as well as about the Django ORM.  And it's super easy once you know how.

Comment: could you tell us how?

Comment: And years later, South is now part of Django core.

Answer (score 18):

You could try getting the SQL for your new field using:

```
manage.py sql appname
```

Where `appname` is the name of the application in which your newspaper class lives.

Then, you could manually add a field to your `appname_newspaper` table, using `ALTER TABLE`. I'm not aware of a way to do this directly with Django, since Django does not support migrations.

Comment: A small comment: if you go this route, I recommend performing the migration (filling in the initial values of the column) in your Django application, by just looking for uninitialized values and doing it on-the-fly. Trying to fill them in from a different application risks running into issues with caching.

Answer (score 1):

2015 answer:

Run the following:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```